# Driver stacktrace in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do following steps

```
df1 = df.na.drop(subset=["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5","Column6"])
df1 =  df1.withColumn('Column6',df1['Column6'].cast(DoubleType()))
udf_dict = udf(lambda x,y: 1 if(x>=y) else 0,IntegerType())
df1 = df1.withColumn('Flag',udf_dict('Column2','Column6'))
filter1 = df1.filter(df1['Flag'] == 1)
```

It is giving me following error

[image]
[image]

Please suggest where it is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are nulls in your dataframe, which causes the UDF to fail. However, there is no need to use an UDF here. You can just filter the dataframe by comparing the two columns directly.

```
df1 = df.na.drop(subset=["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5","Column6"])
df1 = df1.withColumn('Column6',df1['Column6'].cast(DoubleType()))
filter1 = df1.filter('Column2 >= Column6')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just wondering I have dropped all null values of required columns in my first step then why these kind of error occurs?

Comment: @user9482910 sometimes pyspark UDFs ignore the non-null filters for unclear reasons. Even if you dropped nulls, the rows still somehow got processed by the UDF, which leads it to crash

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19844